# .Net Core 2.2 AutoFac Register Dependency that Injects a logger instance

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, autofac

**Tool Versions**

- asp.net core 2.2
- Autofac 4.9.2

**Problem**

I'm trying to inject a logger instance into a class that is already configured for dependency inject by Autofac

**Setup**

I have a class that queries a database.  The class has a connection string injected into it by Autofac.  The below setup works.

Class without the Logger injected:

```cs
public class ItemQueries
        : IItemQueries
    {
        private readonly string _connectionString = default(string);

        public ItemQueries(string connectionString)
        {
            _connectionString = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString) ? connectionString : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
        }

        public async Task<ItemViewModel> GetItemAsync(int id)
        {
            using (var connection = new SqlConnection(_connectionString))
            {
                connection.Open();

                var result = await connection.QueryAsync<dynamic>(
                    @"SELECT *                        
                    FROM dbo.items
                    WHERE Id=@id"
                    , new { id }
                );

                if (result.AsList().Count == 0)
                {
                    throw new KeyNotFoundException();
                }

                return MapItem(result.FirstOrDefault());
            }
        }

        private ItemViewModel MapItem(dynamic result)
        {
            return new ItemViewModel()
            {
                Id = result.Id,
                Name = result.Name
            };
        }
    }
```

This is how I've registered the class with Autofac:

```cs
public class ItemModule
        : Autofac.Module
    {
        public string QueriesConnectionString { get; }

        public ItemModule(string queriesConnectionString)
        {
            QueriesConnectionString = queriesConnectionString;
        }

        protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
        {
            builder.Register(c => new ItemQueries(QueriesConnectionString)) // <-- this breaks when I make the below changes because it's looking for an instance of ILogger<ItemQueries>
                .As<IItemQueries>()
                .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
        }
    }
```

However, I want to inject my Logger instance into the `ItemQueries` class, so I injected it in the constructor as so:

```cs
private readonly ILogger<ItemQueries> _logger;
private readonly string _connectionString = default(string);

        public ItemQueries(ILogger<ItemQueries> logger, string connectionString)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _connectionString = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString) ? connectionString : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
        }
```

But that breaks the registration in my Autofac module.  How do I tell Autofac that the `ItemQueries` class requires the Logger instance to be injected?

I thought Autofac would be able to workout that the `ItemQueries` class needs the `ILogger<>` instance to be inject (you know, as if by magic!)

Comment: `ILogger<T>` is built into core, and core uses it's built-in dependency injection for its own purposes. Is this all  your code? Because you could/should wire up aspnetcore to use your autofac container for injection instead of its own. It's easier to troubleshoot a single container provider than multiple.

Comment: I can move this to an answer instead of a link, but autofac has an example of populating the autofac container with services provided by aspnetcore: https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/integration/aspnetcore.html#controllers-as-services

Comment: You need to use Factorys from autofac

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can resolve things in lambda registrations. That's what the context parameter in the lambda is for.

```
builder
  .Register(c =>
    new ItemQueries(QueriesConnectionString, c.Resolve<ILogger<ItemQueries>>()))
  .As<IItemQueries>()
  .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the feature "Factory" from Autofac.

Here is the setup of your solution with Factory

```
private readonly ILogger<ItemQueries> _logger;
private readonly string _connectionString = default(string);

public delegate ItemQueries Factory(string connectionString); // --> here, you create the delegate factory

// connectionString needs to be the first parameter
public ItemQueries(string connectionString, ILogger<ItemQueries> logger) 
{
    _logger = logger;
    _connectionString = !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(connectionString) ? connectionString : throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(connectionString));
}
```

And the module setup should be like this:

```
public class ItemModule: Autofac.Module
{
    public string QueriesConnectionString { get; }

    public ItemModule(string queriesConnectionString)
    {
        QueriesConnectionString = queriesConnectionString;
    }

    protected override void Load(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.RegisterType<ItemQueries>();  // --> not sure if needed

        builder.Register(c => 
        {
           var factory = c.Resolve<ItemQueries.Factory>();
           return factory.Invoke(QueriesConnectionString);
        })  
        .As<IItemQueries>()
        .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }
}
```